# Dynamically generate a select based on another select

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to generate a list of options in a select dynamically based on the selection in another select by referencing a value in an array of objects.

```
<select id="radar">
    <option value="15">City1</option>
    <option value="64">City2</option>
</select>

<select id="beam">

</select>
```

Objects:

```
var radars = {
  "city1": {
    "name": "city1",
    "maxBeams": 16
  },

  "city2": {
    "name": "city2",
    "maxBeams": 3
  }
}
```

When a radar option is selected for example City2, I would like to fill the beam select with an option for as many maxBeams that have thee option value and text to simply be that index number:

```
<select id="beam">
    <option value="1">1 </option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

What is the simplest way to accomplish this and make it easy to update?

Comment: Start with a `change` event on your `radar` select - on change, check the selected value, and updated your new select.

Comment: Where is your attempt?

Answer (score 1):

You really shouldn't be using javascript to dynamically generate content like this.  You should be using a framework like Vue.js, React, or Angular.  You can homebrew a solution directly with javascript but you're just adding to your technical debt.

You should be doing something like this:

```
<div vue="app">
  <select v-model="city_group">
    <option disabled value="">Please select one</option>
    <option v-for="c in cities">{{c}}</option>
  </select>
  <select v-if="city_group != ''" v-model="city">
    <option disabled value="">Please select one</option>
    <option v-for="c in city_info[city_group]">{{c}}</option>
  </select>
  <h1>My city group is {{city_group}}</h1>
  <h1>My city is {{city}}</h1>
</div>
```

Notice how the content is based on data.
https://codepen.io/Snorghma/pen/QWWjOmq

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Select
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html